# how to define the connection scope of a whole spring project - web service connection scope

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

Is it possible to define the scope of a whole spring project such as `session`, `request` etc?

I have a spring project which is only used as a web service to provide services to other projects, which are forming the application together. In the web service project there are many endpoints which are all accessed via soapMessages from other projects when necessary.

What I would like to achieve is that everytime this web service project responds to its clients, it should close the connection immediatly. I found following solutions but they are not really solutions to this problem:

In the web.xml file I added

```
<session-config>
        <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>       
</session-config>
```

but this is not doing what I would like to do, as it is closing all the sessions every 10 minutes.

I created `.htaccess` file and added

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Connection close
</IfModule>
```

apperently this is not even being evaluated by `Tomcat` and you can only set these properties in the global scope of the server which wouldnt be project specific and apply to all the applications in that server.

By the way I am aware that closing the connection and reopening it at every request will reduce the performance.

Comment: You want to invalidate the session after each request

Comment: How can I do that? and will it apply to the whole project?

Comment: Invalidate session `login.invalidate()` after each request.

Comment: Thanks @Sharan, but I am looking to do this for the whole project in a config file somehow, and not on each request handler

Answer (score 0):

You can use **try with resource**, every time you receive a request on the API. You can open the session with `try-with-resource` and use that session for entire flow, than after the response, the session will be closed automatically with the scope.
Eg :

```
try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {

     Response resp = service.doSomething(session);
     return resp;
}
```

Comment: do I need to do this for every request handler in the api?